# Not getting Text on my Image in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
 .relative{
    position:relative; 
    width:600px;
}
.absolute-text{
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0; 
    font-size:24px; 
    font-family:"vedana"; 
    background:rgba(251,251,251,0.5);
    padding:10px 20px; 
    width:100%; 
    text-align:center;
}
.absolute-text a{
    font-size:16px; 
    color:#b92b27;
}
```

**I want to write the movie name and movie star name on the image which will come from Back End But I am not able to do this.**

```
 <div class="relative">
      <img src="{{{movie.Poster}}" alt="">
      <p class="absolute-text">{{movie.Title}} </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of typos I noticed. First, the `relative` class needs a period.

```
.relative{
    position:relative; 
    width:600px;
}
```

Secondly, you've got too many curly braces in your image source:

```
<div class="relative">
      <img src="{{movie.Poster}}" alt="">
      <p class="absolute-text">{{movie.Title}} </p>
</div>
```

Assuming these are not the culprit(s), have you inspected the `absolute-text` element to see if it's appearing in the DOM? If it is appearing in the DOM but you can't see it on the page you can try giving it a z-index property that's greater than 0, for example:

```
.absolute-text{
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0; 
    font-size:24px; 
    font-family:"vedana"; 
    background:rgba(251,251,251,0.5);
    padding:10px 20px; 
    width:100%; 
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Finally, is your `movie.Title` scoped properly? What I mean is do you have something that resembles `$scope.movie.Title =` somewhere in your controller?

Comment: yeah, Its appearing in the Page.

Comment: Progress. So, to be clear, you're seeing the element appear on the page, just not the text for the movie, is that correct? Try giving your `.absolute-text` element a display property, like `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: yeah, that is the problem.

Comment: Will you check the spelling of the `font-family` property for `.absolute-text`? It should be `verdana` and it doesn't need quotes around it. Also, add a height property as well, say 30px, for testing purposes.

Comment: Are you seeing the correct movie title appear in the DOM?

Comment: Thanks Dude, Its working now, thanks for making me correct.

Comment: Awesome! Will you accept my answer please? Glad to help ;)